# onclick in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick

There seems to be a lot of questions about Chrome and onclick, but I haven't found one that helps.

I have a code snippet (generated by php)

```
<td class=data>
<a onclick="document.getElementById('image37082').style.visibility='visible';">show image</a><br>
<img id="image37082" style="visibility:hidden" src="file://D:\Data\2013\201312\20131217\INT_20131217_171110_preview.png">
</td>
```

that ought to just work, but it doesn't in Chrome (it does in Firefox).

What I want to happen is that the image appears when the "show image" text is clicked.

Comment: Always use relative URLs for image: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83r2U/

Comment: Try `file:///D:/Data/2013/201312/20131217/INT_20131217_171110_preview.png`I have added another slash after file and have turned all your slashes around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome may not allow you to access local files for security reasons.

Also, you should use file://**/** instead of file://. And replace the \'s with /'s.

Comment: I think that this is what the fundamental problem is... I'm deliberately trying to access a set of images for my experiment that are stored on my local hard-drive. I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: Is there no way for you to copy those images to the server side? In case your own computer is also hosting the website this should be very easy. You could simply move the images to where you keep your .php files, then address them like so: http://localhost/images/2013/201312/20131217/INT_20131217_171110_preview.png

Comment: Maybe, but it's a waste of disk space to have them double copied. I'm thinking of network mounting my local disk on the server (which is actually just my another computer on my desk). It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works fine for me in all major browsers. I would resommend puttin gthe image somehow into your sites folder somewhere and use it from there. Your script is fine.